# VIsual basic As/400 connection

Tags: vb.net, db2-400

I need to create a visual basic application connecting to AS/400.
I've read that odbc driver are needed but i don't know how to find/download/install them.
It is necessary to install iSeries access or is ok only download Fix Packs, register ibm odbc driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the install package for either [IBM iAccess for Windows (iAW)](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows.html) or the newer [IBM iAccess Client Solutions (ACS)](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/solutions.html) with the **Windows Application Package**

You might be able to just install the Windows Application Package portition of ACS.  But I've never tried it.